# error 404 when I try to call a route in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing, http-status-code-404, angular-routing

I have an issue in angular. I have a list of clients, and I want to create a link, with an ID on the name of the client. I wish when you click on the name, a list of user of that client show up on a new page.
I have two components :

Client.component

```
export interface TablePaginationLabels {
    first?: string;
    last?: string;
    next?: string;
    pageSize?: string;
    previous?: string;
    position?: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-client',
    templateUrl: './client.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client.component.scss'],
    entryComponents:    [LinkIAComponent, LinkUserComponent],
    providers: [DatesFormatPipe]
})
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {
    
    client!: IClient;
    /* variables du tableau  */
    tableHeaders: any[] = [];

    tableBody: any[] = [];

    currentFilters = {
        idClient: '',
        nameClient: '',
        codePac:'',
        compagnyId: '',
        site: '',
        version: '',
    };

    rowClicked: TableRowClickEvent[] = [];
    columnSorted!: TableSortEvent;

    selectType = true;

    selectedBoolean = false;

    isLoading = true;

    isOptionSlideInOpen = false;

    /* variables du paginator  */
    @Input() rowsPerPage = 20;
    totalClients = 100;
    currentPage = 1;
    
    @Input() public listeCompagnyid: Array<number> = [];

    @Input() pageSizes = [{ label: '5', value: 5 }, { label: '10', value: 10 }, { label: '20', value: 20 }, { label: '50', value: 50 }];
    pageLabels: Partial<TablePaginatorLabels> =
        {
            first: 'première page',
            last: 'dernière page',
            next: 'page suivante',
            pageSize: 'Clients par page',
            previous: 'page précédente',
            position: 'sur'
        }
        ;
        
    languageSelection: any;
    languages = [{ name: 'English', value: 0 }, { name: 'French', value: 1 }];

    constructor(
        public datesFormatPipe: DatesFormatPipe,
        public clientService: ClientService,
        public alertService: AlertService,
        public router: Router,
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if ((JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterCriteria')!) !== null) && this.isFilterEmpty()) {
            this.currentFilters = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterCriteria')!);
        }
        this.getClientsList(this.currentPage, this.totalClients);
        this.languageSelection = this.languages[1];
    }

    /**
     * Récupère la liste des clients
     * @param offset la page courante
     * @param limit le nombre de clients
     */
    getClientsList(offset: number, limit: number): void {

        const criteria = [];
        if (!this.isFilterEmpty()) {
            if (this.currentFilters.idClient !== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'idClient.equals', value: this.currentFilters.idClient });
            }
            if (this.currentFilters.nameClient !== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'nameClient.in', value: this.currentFilters.nameClient });
            }
            if (this.currentFilters.codePac !== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'codePac.in', value: this.currentFilters.codePac });
            }
            if (this.currentFilters.compagnyId !== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'compagnyId.in', value: this.currentFilters.compagnyId });
            }
            if (this.currentFilters.site!== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'site.in', value: this.currentFilters.site });
            }
            if (this.currentFilters.version!== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'version.in', value: this.currentFilters.version });
            }
        }

        this.selectedBoolean = false;

        this.isLoading = true;

        this.initializeTableHeaders();
        
        this.clientService
            .query({ page: offset, size: limit, criteria })
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IClient[]>) => this.paginateClients(res.body!),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }

    /*
     * Méthode qui affiche un message d'erreur
     */
    onError(errorMessage: string): void {
        this.alertService.addAlert({ type: 'danger', message: errorMessage });
    }

    /**
     *  Map le client en tableau afin de l'afficher
     * @param data
     */
    paginateClients(data: IClient[]): void {
    
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
        this.tableBody = data.map((t: IClient) => [
            {
                value: t,
                component: LinkUserComponent,
                inputs:{
                    routerLink: `/${t.compagnyId}/utilisateurs`,
                    label: t.nameClient,
                }
            },
            t.codePac,
            t.compagnyId,
            t.nameVersion,
        ]);
        this.isLoading = false;
        
    }

    stringToDate(date: any): Date {
        const monthDayYear = date.split('-');
        return new Date(parseInt(monthDayYear[0], 10), // year
            parseInt(monthDayYear[1], 10) - 1, // month
            parseInt(monthDayYear[2], 10)); // day
    }

    /* évènements du tableau */
    selectedRows($event: any): void {
        this.rowClicked = $event;
    }

    onSort($event: any): void {
        // revenir à la page 1
        this.currentPage = 1;
        // trier sur l'ensemble des données
        this.columnSorted = $event;
    }

    /* évènements du paginator */
    navigateToPage($event: Event): void {
        this.currentPage = Number($event);
        this.getClientsList((this.currentPage - 1) * this.rowsPerPage, this.rowsPerPage);
    }

    changePageSize($event: Event): void {
        this.rowsPerPage = Number($event);
        this.getClientsList(1, this.rowsPerPage);
    }

    applyFilters(newFilters: any): void {
        this.currentFilters = newFilters;
        this.getClientsList(this.currentPage, this.totalClients);
    }

    select(id: number): void {
        const index = this.tableBody.findIndex(row => row[0].value === id);
        const bool = this.tableBody[index][0].inputs.checked;
        this.tableBody[index][0].inputs.checked = !bool;
    }

    selectAll(): void {
        for (const row of this.tableBody) {
            if (row[0].inputs.disabled === false) {
                row[0].inputs.checked = !this.selectedBoolean;
            }
        }
        this.selectedBoolean = !this.selectedBoolean;
    }

    isFilterEmpty(): boolean {
        if (this.currentFilters.idClient !== '') {
            return false;
        } else if (this.currentFilters.nameClient !== '') {
            return false;
        } else if (this.currentFilters.codePac !== '') {
            return false;
        } else if (this.currentFilters.compagnyId !== '') {
            return false;
        } else if (this.currentFilters.site !== '') {
            return false;
        } else if (this.currentFilters.version !== '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    openSlideIn(): void {
        this.isOptionSlideInOpen = !this.isOptionSlideInOpen;
        this.initializeTableHeaders();
    }

    initializeTableHeaders(): void {
        this.tableHeaders = [
            { label: 'Connection IA', sort: true },
            { label: 'Nom Client', sort: true },
            { label: 'Code Pac', sort: true },
            { label: 'Compagny Id', sort: true },
            { label: 'Version', sort: true },
        ];
    }
    
}
```

And I want to got to the route `/${t.compagnyId}/utilisateurs`, this page is suppose to show a list of user with the user.component :

```
export interface TablePaginationLabels {
    first?: string;
    last?: string;
    next?: string;
    pageSize?: string;
    previous?: string;
    position?: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
    providers: [DatesFormatPipe]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    client!: IClient;
    /* variables du tableau  */
    tableHeaders: any[] = [];

    tableBody: any[] = [];

    currentFilters = {
        compagnyIdFilter: '',
    };
    
    rowClicked: TableRowClickEvent[] = [];
    columnSorted!: TableSortEvent;

    selectType = true;

    selectedBoolean = false;

    relaunchActivateButton = true;

    isLoading = true;

    isOptionSlideInOpen = false;

    
    /* variables du paginator  */
    @Input() rowsPerPage = 20;
    totalUsers = 100;
    currentPage = 1;

    @Input() pageSizes = [{ label: '5', value: 5 }, { label: '10', value: 10 }, { label: '20', value: 20 }, { label: '50', value: 50 }];
    pageLabels: Partial<TablePaginatorLabels> =
        {
            first: 'première page',
            last: 'dernière page',
            next: 'page suivante',
            pageSize: 'Clients par page',
            previous: 'page précédente',
            position: 'sur'
        }
        ;

    languageSelection: any;
    languages = [{ name: 'English', value: 0 }, { name: 'French', value: 1 }];

    constructor(
        public datesFormatPipe: DatesFormatPipe,
        public UserService: UserService,
        public alertService: AlertService,
        public router: Router,
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.route.data.subscribe(({ currentClient }) => {
            this.client = currentClient;
        });
            
            if ((JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterCriteria')!) !== null) ) {
                this.currentFilters = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterCriteria')!);
            }
    //        this.initAdditionalColumn();
            this.getUsersList(this.currentPage, this.totalUsers);
            this.languageSelection = this.languages[1];
        }
    
    /**
     * Récupère la liste des clients
     * @param offset la page courante
     * @param limit le nombre de clients
     */
    getUsersList(offset: number, limit: number): void {

        const criteria = [];
        if (!this.isFilterEmpty()) {
            if (this.currentFilters.compagnyIdFilter !== '') {
                criteria.push({ key: 'idUser.in', value: this.currentFilters.compagnyIdFilter });
            }
        }

        this.selectedBoolean = false;

        this.isLoading = true;

        this.initializeTableHeaders();
        
        this.UserService
//          .getUsersByCompagnyId(this.client.compagnyId)
            .query({ page: offset, size: limit})
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => this.paginateUsers(res.body!),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }
    
    /**
     *  Map le client en tableau afin de l'afficher
     * @param data
     */
    paginateUsers(data: IUser[] ): void {
            
            this.tableBody = data.map((t: IUser) =>[
            t.idUser,
            t.firstName,
        t.lastName,
        t.employeeNumber,
        ]);
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
        

        this.isLoading = false;

//        this.checkToActivateRelaunchButton();
    }
    
    /*
     * Méthode qui affiche un message d'erreur
     */
    onError(errorMessage: string): void {
        this.alertService.addAlert({ type: 'danger', message: errorMessage });
    }
    
    stringToDate(date: any): Date {
        const monthDayYear = date.split('-');
        return new Date(parseInt(monthDayYear[0], 10), // year
            parseInt(monthDayYear[1], 10) - 1, // month
            parseInt(monthDayYear[2], 10)); // day
    }

    /* évènements du tableau */
    selectedRows($event: any): void {
        this.rowClicked = $event;
    }

    onSort($event: any): void {
        // revenir à la page 1
        this.currentPage = 1;
        // trier sur l'ensemble des données
        this.columnSorted = $event;
    }

    /* évènements du paginator */
    navigateToPage($event: Event): void {
        this.currentPage = Number($event);
        this.getUsersList( (this.currentPage - 1) * this.rowsPerPage, this.rowsPerPage);
    }

    changePageSize($event: Event): void {
        this.rowsPerPage = Number($event);
        this.getUsersList(1, this.rowsPerPage);
    }

    applyFilters(newFilters: any): void {
        this.currentFilters = newFilters;
        this.getUsersList(this.currentPage, this.totalUsers);
    }
    
    select(idUser: string): void {
        const index = this.tableBody.findIndex(row => row[0].value === idUser);
        const bool = this.tableBody[index][0].inputs.checked;
        this.tableBody[index][0].inputs.checked = !bool;
        this.checkToActivateRelaunchButton();
    }

    selectAll(): void {
        for (const row of this.tableBody) {
            if (row[0].inputs.disabled === false) {
                row[0].inputs.checked = !this.selectedBoolean;
            }
        }
        this.selectedBoolean = !this.selectedBoolean;
        this.checkToActivateRelaunchButton();
    }

    checkToActivateRelaunchButton(): void {
        let bool = true;
        for (const row of this.tableBody) {
            if (row[0].inputs.checked === true) {
                bool = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.relaunchActivateButton = bool;
    }
    
    isFilterEmpty(): boolean {
        if (this.currentFilters.compagnyIdFilter !== '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    openSlideIn(): void {
        this.isOptionSlideInOpen = !this.isOptionSlideInOpen;
        this.initializeTableHeaders();
    }
    
    initializeTableHeaders(): void {
        this.tableHeaders = [
            { label: 'ID', sort: true },
            { label: 'Prénom', sort: true },
            { label: 'Nom', sort: true },
            { label: 'Matricule', sort: true },
        ];
    }
   
 }
```

But when in my navigator, I have a the page of error 404 who show up. I search and I find that the compagnyId in the clientComponent don't go to the user.component. I try many things but somethings missing, or I miss to do something. I have for every entities a folder service, route and module. I am in this issues for 2 weeks and I need some help ;)

this my client.service :

```
// type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IClient>;
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IClient[]>;
type EntityResponseTypeUser = HttpResponse<IUser>;
type EntityArrayResponseTypeUser = HttpResponse<IUser[]>;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ClientService {
    public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/clients';

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

    find(compagnyId: string): Observable<EntityResponseTypeUser> {
        return this.http
            .get<IUser>(`${this.resourceUrl}/utilisateurs`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http
            .get<IClient[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
    }
    
    getUsersByCompagnyId(compagnyId: string): Observable<EntityArrayResponseTypeUser>{
        return this.http
            .get<IUser[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${compagnyId}/utilisateurs`, { observe: 'response' });
    }
    
    getNameFilter(): Observable<HttpResponse<SelectOption[]>> {
        return this.http
            .get<SelectOption[]>(this.resourceUrl + '/filter/client', { observe: 'response' });
    }
    
    getVersionFilter(): Observable<HttpResponse<SelectOption[]>> {
        return this.http
            .get<SelectOption[]>(this.resourceUrl + '/filter/version', { observe: 'response' });
    }
    
    getSiteFilter(): Observable<HttpResponse<SelectOption[]>> {
        return this.http
            .get<SelectOption[]>(this.resourceUrl + '/filter/site', { observe: 'response' });
    }
}
```

and my user.service :

```
type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IUser>;
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IUser[]>;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/utilisateurs';

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

    find(idUser: string): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        
        return this.http
            .get<IUser>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${idUser}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http
                .get<IUser[]>(this.resourceUrl, {params: options, observe: 'response'} );
    }
    
    getUsersByCompagnyId(compagnyId: string, req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType>{
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        
        return this.http.get<IUser[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${compagnyId}`, {params: options, observe: 'response'});
    }
    
    getCompagnyIdFilter(): Observable<HttpResponse<SelectOption[]>>{
        return this.http
            .get<SelectOption[]>(this.resourceUrl + '/filter/compagnyId', { observe: 'response' });
    }
 }
```

and I put here my client.route if needed :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ClientResolve implements Resolve<IUser> {
    constructor(private service: ClientService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<IUser> {
        const compagnyid = route.params['compagnyId'] ? route.params['compagnyId'] : null;
        if (compagnyid) {
            return this.service.find(compagnyid).pipe(
                filter((response: HttpResponse<User>) => response.ok),
                map((user: HttpResponse<User>) => user.body!)
            );
        }
        return of(new User('', ''));
    }
}

export const ClientRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ClientComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: [], // 'ROLE_USER'
            // defaultSort: 'id,asc',
            pageTitle: 'loginpageApp.client.home.title'
        }
    },
    {
        
        path: '/:compagnyId/utilisateurs',
//      path: '/sites'
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: {
            user: ClientResolve
        },
        data: {
            authorities: [], // 'ROLE_USER'
            pageTitle: 'loginpageApp.client.home.title'
        }
        
    },
];
```

and my user.route :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserResolve implements Resolve<IUser> {
    constructor(private service: UserService, private router: Router) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<IUser> {
        const idUser = route.params['idUser'] ? route.params['idUser'] : null;
        if (idUser) {
            return this.service.find(idUser).pipe(
                filter((response: HttpResponse<IUser>) => response.ok),
                map((user: HttpResponse<User>) => user.body!)

            );
        }
        return of(new User(''));
    }
}

export const UserRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: [], // 'ROLE_USER'
            // defaultSort: 'id,asc',
            pageTitle: 'loginpageApp.user.home.title'
        }
    },
];
```